# Count the number of sub arrays such that each element in the subarray appears at least twice

Tags: python, list, complexity-theory

I have come across a problem and can't seem to come up with an efficient solution. The problem is as follows:

Given an array A, count the number of consecutive contiguous subarrays such that each element in the subarray appears at least twice.

Ex, for:

```
A = [0,0,0]
```

The answer should be 3 because we have

```
A[0..1] = [0,0]
A[1..2] = [0,0]
A[0..3] = [0,0,0]
```

Another example:

```
A=[1,2,1,2,3]
```

The answer should be 1 because we have:

```
A[0..3] = [1,2,1,2]
```

I can't seem to come up with an efficient solution for this algorithm. I have an algorithm that checks every possible subarray (O(n^2)), but I need something better. This is my naive solution:

```
def duplicatesOnSegment(arr):
    total = 0
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        unique = 0
        test = {}
        for j in range(i,len(arr)):
            k = arr[j]
            if k not in test:
                test[k] = 1
            else:
                test[k] +=  1

            if test[k] == 1:
                unique += 1
            elif test[k] == 2:
                unique -= 1
            if unique == 0:
                total += 1
    return total
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program in the worst case is greater than O(n^2) as you are using `if k not in test` in nested loop. This `in` in worst case is O(n) resulting in overall worst case O(n^3). I have this, O(n^2) in worst, solution which uses `collections.defaultdict` as hash to make this faster.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def func(A):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        counter = 0
        hash = defaultdict (int)
        for j in range (i, len(A)):
            hash[A[j]] += 1
            if hash[A[j]] == 2:
                counter += 1
            if counter != 0 and counter == len(hash):
                result += 1
    return result
```

Comment: Explanation: `counter` tracks how many values in the current subarray appear at least twice. If all distinct elements appear twice, we have a valid subarray, hence increment `result`

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I would consider the negation of the property of interest :

`not(all(x in l appears at least twice)) = exists(x in l such that any other y in l != x)`

Not sure yet that the previous reformulation of your question might help, but my intuition as a mathematician told me to try this way... Still feels like O(n^2) though...

```py
my_list = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'c']

def remaining_list(el,list):
    assert el in list
    if el == list[-1]: return []
    else: return list[list.index(el)+1:]

def has_duplicate(el, list):
    assert el in list
    return el in remaining_list(el,list)

list(filter(lambda e:not(has_duplicate(e,my_list)),my_list))
```

Comment: To my understanding, this doesn't answer the question, as it simply filters out all unique elements (which could be done in linear time with hashmaps). The question asks for the number of contiguous subarrays that appear in the array